# kotlin var with different return type on getter

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to hold a property of type X that extends Y, the getter should return Y and setter should be private and accept X.

Is this possible via a simple var definition, or do I need to use fun ?

Comment: i think you'll need to use `fun` because the types are different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider using additional [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties):

```
class Sample {
    private var privateX: X
    var publicY: Y
        get() = privateX
}
```